# Jquery if else statement (else not working)

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want thumb to have class new when the page loads and remove the class new when I click a button. That works fine. Now I want to say that if thumb does have class new, then div info should be hidden, and if it doesn't, it should show.

I understand this is to do with thumb having the new class added when the page loads, but why can't I override than on the click function?

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new');

$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.thumb').removeClass('new');
});

if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new')) {
    $('.info-top').hide();
} else {
    $('.info-top').show();
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/Xd9DA/)

Comment: How about putting the statement inside the event handler.

Comment: And that if statement will never work, you're always removing the class

Comment: What happens with your code is that when you click the button you remove the class, that's it. If you expect that this change is carried when you reload the page, you're thinking it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**like this** http://jsfiddle.net/qe4nM/

- Take a note on the function `callmeman` you need to call the function on the events you need them to be invoked.

It can be simplified depending on your reqs. like use `toggle`

Hope rest fits the need `:)`

**code**

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new');
callmeman();

 $('#Button').click(function () {
     $('.thumb').removeClass('new');
     callmeman();
 });

 function callmeman(){
     if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new')) {
         $('.info-top').hide();
      } else {
         $('.info-top').show();
     }
 }
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you and everyone else for your answers, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems in your fiddle:

1) You are targeting the id `button` in your JS, but you gave the div an ID of `Button`. JS is case-sensitive, so they need to match

2) The anchor inside the div is reloading your page onclick so you will never see the effect you are looking for unless you stop that element from performing it's intended action usingjQuery's [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on it. I would move your click event to the anchor entirely, preventDefault, and change your removeClass to a toggle. Here is your fiddle forked with that work done: http://jsfiddle.net/ftE5W/1/

HTML

```
<div><a id="button" href="#">Button</a></div>
<div class="info-top">Info</div>
<div class="thumb">Thumb</div>
```

JS

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new');

$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('.thumb').toggleClass('new');
});

if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new')) {
    $('.info-top').hide();
    $('.thumb').removeClass('new'); 
}
else {
    $('.info-top').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into event handler

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumb').addClass('new');

    $('#Button').click(function(){
        $('.thumb').removeClass('new');
     });

    if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new')) {
        $('.info-top').hide();
     } else {
        $('.info-top').show();
     }
});
```

`$(function() { .... });` is alternative of `$(document.body).ready(function(){...});`

By the way you misspelled *id*. You should change `"#button"` into `"#Button"`.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0nSDlfUi2c

Answer (score 0):

Your functions with hide() and show() functions are called only once during page loading. You should include it in click listener.

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new');

$('#button').click(function(){

    $('.thumb').removeClass('new');
    if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new')) {
        $('.info-top').hide();
    } else {
      $('.info-top').show();
}
});
```

But it doesn't look very well, I would change this code a bit

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new');
$('.info-top').show()

$('#button').click(function(){

    $('.thumb').removeClass('new');
    $('.info-top').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the button id, you misspelled

```
$('#button')
```

instead of

```
$('#Button')
```